# For what $r,s$ exist unbiased estimation of $f(p) = p^{r}(1 - p)^{s}$ for binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, binomial-distribution

We have sample $x_1, ..., x_n$ generated by independent binomial random variables $\xi_1, ..., \xi_n$.

We know parameter $k$ but don't know probability $p$.

k is number of tests: $\xi_i \sim Binomial(k,p)$

The task is to find numbers $r,s$, that there is exist unbiased estimation for $$f(p) = p^{r}(1 - p)^{s}$$

The problem is that I don't understand the general approach how to test existence of unbiased estimation.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Are $k$ and $n$ the same thing?

Comment: @Henry , no, not the same.

Comment: So what is the $k$ that you know?

Comment: @Henry in the problem just said that k is known parameter. So I can't answer your question. Might I misunderstand something, of course.

Comment: k is number of tests. $\xi_i$~$Binomial(k,p)$

Comment: Suppose you have an unbiased estimator $U$ that depends on sufficient statistic $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\sim B(nk,p)$ Then $E(U)=\sum_{j=0}^{nk} \binom {nk}{j}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}U(j)=p^r(1-p)^s$. LHS is a polynomial of degree at most $nk$, so you can solve for $U$ iff $r$ and $s$ are non-negative integers with $r+s\le nk$.

Comment: It's great. Why Does it depend on $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$ and not only in on $x_1,\dots,x_n$?

Comment: @A.S. I have the same question as Evgeny. Why  $U$ depends on sum, and not on  $x_1, ..., x_n$?

Comment: Sum is the [sufficient statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Bernoulli_distribution) - so $U$ depends only on the sum and not on the summands themselves. Overall you make has $nk$ Bernouillis - it doesn't matter how you break them up. For a fixed sum, all possibly arrangements are equally likely and probability of each arrangement depends on the sum only. @Evgen

Comment: @A.S. Yep, I get it. Also, as $x_i$ iid, one can forward write they joint distribution as product. We have same answer, but no need to "sufficient statisitc" knowladge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it is equivalent to think that you have an $iid$ sample of $m=nk$ Bernoulli random variables with probability of success being $p$. An unbiased estimator exists when $r+s\leq m-1$. Check out Chapter 2 of Statistical Implications of Turing's Formula (by Zhang), John Wiley & Sons 2017.